# truth table from logic circuit

Tags: logic-gates

How should a truth table look for the logic circuit below if there is one output that is determined by just one of the inputs?
[image]

[image]

Comment: This looks like homework so you need to show some effort as we're not a free homework service. Label each of the gates and each of the outputs (or redraw the diagram with the CircuitLab button on the editor toolbar and it will label everything for you) and then start drawing out the truth tables.

Comment: You need to make an effort to create these truth tables yourself. If some output is determined by only the value of input 'A' then that output will simply have the same value regardless of the value of input 'B'.

Comment: I already have a truth table but I'm not sure if I did it correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your truth table is correct.

Your update with labelling also makes everything unambiguous and clear which is a major help in validating and troubleshooting.

Answer (score 0):

The format that you used for the truth table looks fine to me. Two inputs and three outputs. Ones and zeros in the cells.

I didn't check whether the content of the table was correct. This would be impossible since you haven't labeled any of the signals, and in any event that was not the question.

Comment: I edited a question